Dynamic row values stored in table calculation based on expression
Below is my table



Product
Formula
Total




FA1
NULL
50


FA2
NULL
60


FA
FA1+FA2



CA1
NULL
40


CA2
NULL
30


CA
CA1-CA2




--> after calculation need to updated this as 110 (FA1+FA2) to row FA
--> after calculation need to updated this as 10 (CA1-CA2) to row CA
Is there any way to evaluate this expression with out loops
Also need a logic to access Formula column to compute result
Expected result



Product
Formula
Total




FA1
NULL
50


FA2
NULL
60


FA
FA1+FA2
110  (FA1+FA2)


CA1
NULL
40


CA2
NULL
30


CA
CA1-CA2
10   (CA1-CA2)




I don't get this. Could you please show both sample input data and expected result? If further rows appear let's say with product FA0, FA5, FA100, will the formula be changed? If so, how? Why store the formula in this table?

is the formula really a column in your table?

Updated the expected result , this is what in production now currently there is no way to change now, it was used in C# formula calculation earlier but due to performance we want to utilize database to calculate from Stored procedure, any help appreciated thanks

@eshirvana unfortunately yes and that code was worked by other team and project came to us

oh, so that would be a different formula for each column?!! that's not going to work, you need to hardcode each formula in your query for each case

Storing expressions in a table, to be executed by the data engine, is a ticking time bomb. Imagine if someone writes the expression to be 1 FROM sys,tables; DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable; SELECT 1' or something far more malicious...

It's a really bad idea to remove logic from your application (here C#) to the database and I doubt this will ever improve the performance. SQL and especially SQL Server are not good and not designed for this purpose. Their purpose is to store data and provide some simple operations like aggregate/window functions. Why do you think it would be faster/better to put complex logic there? I recommend to leave the logic in C#. If it's too slow, check why rather than move it to somewhere else.

Can your calculations be nested like with CAFA as FA/CA or more complicated like XX as (FA1+CA1)/(FA2-CA2)? You may need both a recursive evaluator process (with loop protection) and a recursive expression parser. Either or both would best be done using an application language, not SQL.

@TN let me try that, but application language running for 10k records gonna kill cpu usage

@JonasMetzler problem with C# is its reading dataset from database and running formulas for almost 10k records so C# is bad in those cases

@JamesAcereoin - You haven't answered the question regarding nested references or complex formulas. To expand on those questions, what defines the allowable syntax for the formulas - allowed names regex, data types, numeric constants, supported operators(+,-,*,/,^,unary -), operator precedence (left to right or traditional priorities), allowed functions (min, max, abs, power, log, trig), nested operation syntax (parenthesis?), error handling rules (syntax error, undefined reference, divide by zero, underflow/overflow). You need a precise and well-defined formula syntax before you can proceed.

@JamesAcereoin The problem is not C#. C# is a quite good language for such logic, especially when using entity framework. If it's running too slow, you made mistakes. Fix them rather than moving the logic to the database. 10k rows can easily be processed by C# logic if correctly implemented.

You can put this thing into excel, i'm pretty sure it would be faster. Don't think SQL is the way to go, but if you load the rows into C# it shouldn't be too bad. Btw, why not let your other team fix this? I'd pay good money to see their solution

This looks like someone has simply dumped excel into sql in the expectation that the 2 products are interchangeable.
